# How should I use Roslyn to compile a .NET Core console application from a .NET Core console application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

My .NET Core console application has the following .csproj (note the NuGet package reference):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.netcore" Version="1.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And here's my .NET Core console application's source code, with the .NET Core console application I'm trying to compile contained in the 'source' variable:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string source =
@"using System;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}";

        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            assemblyName: "source",
            syntaxTrees: new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source) },
            references: new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location) });
        var compilationDiagnostics = compilation.GetDiagnostics();
    }
}
```

The compilationDiagnostics report the following:

> error CS0117: 'Console' does not contain a definition for 'ReadLine'

I'm confused because I can use Console.ReadLine() fine from .NET Core apps compiled normally. I'm getting the metadata reference in the way I saw some examples online do it. The assembly that it references is:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.0\System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll

Using ILSpy on that assembly I can see that Console only has signatures for Write and WriteLine, so the error makes sense in that regard. I guess I need to do the metadata reference differently, but how?